# CSS positioning in IE8 causing headache

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm running a little main navigation test at http://tools.weddingideasmag.com/MainNavTest/

The trouble is, I can't get the drop menu to work right in IE8. The submenus are positioned absolutely, but in IE8 they're way to the right. It's no surprise to say this is only looking like this on IE!

This is what the page looks like on Chrome and is exactly where the menu should be positioned…

[image]

And here is what it looks like on IE8…

[image]

All of the submenus should show directly below the parent link. Can anyone help please, it's driving me nuts!

Comment: Why are you doing this to the submenus parent `li a`? `/*position : relative;*/` It also needs to be on the `li` not the `a`.

Comment: I'm using this script from Code Canyon as the basis Josh - http://codecanyon.net/item/flat-ui-navigation-mega-menu/5837705 it's simply what was created by that author. It's not all my own work but Im using it as a basis for what I need :-)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their nearest positioned - i.e. non-statically positioned - parent. In Chrome, if you don't assign `top` or `left` values to the absolute child, it happens to position it in the "correct" place (not something that should be depended on). Not so with IE8.

This will solve your issue:

```
div.flat-nav>ul>li { position: relative; }
```

Although, when you do that, you'll have to specifically give your dropdowns a width (otherwise they will be constrained to the width of their `li` parent. Additionally, you need to specify `left:0`

```
div.flat-nav ul.column-based { left:0; width: XXXpx; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam - it's putting the submenu in the right place but the ul elements within the submenus are now stacked vertically - they should align left to right

Comment: Give the submenus a width that is wide enough to allow the elements appear side by side.

Comment: I've done that now Adam, but still have a problem with the submenus overlapping in IE

Comment: I don't know what overlapping means? Can you provide a link?

Comment: I have no idea why that would be happening without seeing the code that you are using.